# Typescript Object dynamic assignment changes fieldName

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am creating a new Object using some values from existing Object. Now while assigning fieldId with crs.parentFieldId, In final Object, fieldId name Itself changed to parentFieldId. What gone wrong here?
1. code snippet

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter EditSubfieldFeePage');
    this.fs.getCourseFieldBySelectedId().subscribe((cf: CourseField) => {
      let ids = this.fs.getSelectedCourses();
      for(let crs of cf.courses) {
        if(ids.has(crs.courseId)) {
          let courseFee: CourseFee = {
            fieldId: crs.parentFieldId,
            fieldName: cf.fieldName,
            courseId: crs.courseId,
            courseName: crs.courseName,
            feeAmount: 0,
            feeType: "MONTHLY"
          }
          this.courseFeeList.push(crs);
        }
      }

    });
  }
```

class definition

```
export class CourseFee {
  fieldId: string;
  courseId: string;
  feeAmount: number;
  feeType: string;
}
```

It works fine but in console fieldId is renamed to parentFieldId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're not adding the new `courseFee` object but the `crs` object (which has the `parentFieldId` property)

```
if(ids.has(crs.courseId)) {
  let courseFee: CourseFee = {
    fieldId: crs.parentFieldId,
    fieldName: cf.fieldName,
    courseId: crs.courseId,
    courseName: crs.courseName,
    feeAmount: 0,
    feeType: "MONTHLY"
  }
  this.courseFeeList.push(crs); // <--- here!
}
```

In order to fix it, change this line

`this.courseFeeList.push(crs);`

to be

`this.courseFeeList.push(courseFee);`

Comment: My bad. I did this silly mistake and debugging flow up and down.

Comment: Been there, done that... Glad to hear that is working now :)